# Facing Error in Deploying JAVA EE Web Application

Tags: mysql, servlets, netbeans, glassfish, ejb

I am creating a simple JAVA EE web application , With JSP, Servlet, EJB and glassfish in Netbeans IDE. After creating my Persistence Context, my project is build correctly but I can't Deploy it and this Error is shown:

> GlassFish Server 4.1.1, deploy, null, false E:\Java Code\JAVA EE
>   Web\CRUDWEB\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1056: The module has not been
>   deployed. See the server log for details. BUILD FAILED (total time: 3
>   seconds)

Comment: Where is the log ? Any exceptions ?

Comment: if i click the build-impl.xml:1056 line, the line is
<target if="netbeans.home" name="-run-deploy-nb">
        <nbdeploy clientUrlPart="${client.urlPart}" debugmode="true" forceRedeploy="${forceRedeploy}"/>
    </target>



And i couldn't find any exceptions in the log...how to check the log efficiently? can provide me the steps..i am noob in this field

Comment: Anyone there ro help me? :'(

Comment: You need to open server log view in Netbeans to see the error messages from the server. Or go direclly to the `server.log` file in the GlassFish installation, in `glassfish/domains/domain1/logs`.